# Mensagem do navegador atrapalhando a experiência do usuário

Tags: php, html

Tenho uma página PHP com formulário de pesquisa de produtos. Assim que o usuário faz a pesquisa eu atualizo os produtos da página onde o usuário entra no detalhamento do produto em outra página. A página é responsiva, portanto, o usuário  utiliza a aplicação no celular. E uma função básica pra quem quer abrir a página anterior é clicar no botão "voltar" do próprio aparelho. Ou mesmo no navegador desktop. O problema quando o usuário usa o voltar. Sempre cai na página de reenvio de formulário, onde o usuário mais leigo acha que é um erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem alguma técnica para não cair nessa mensagem?

No filtro do meu formulário está assim:

```
if(isset($_POST['referencia'])&&$_POST['referencia']!=""){
    $_SESSION['referencia_c']=$_POST['referencia'];
}
if(isset($_SESSION['referencia_c'])){
    $filtro .= " AND LOWER(p.descricao) LIKE LOWER('%".$_SESSION['referencia_c']."%') ";
}
```

Comment: Uma técnica que usaria para evitar esse transtorno era usar Ajax. Já pensou em fazer isso?

Comment: Mas mesmo eu fazendo em ajax, depois que eu entrar em outra página e voltar pra página de pesquisa, esse erro não acontece?

Comment: Se você fizer da forma correta, usando Ajax, não acontece.

Comment: Como, geralmente, esse erro acontece ao enviar um formulário, edite sua pergunta e coloque seu formulário html.

Comment: Vou editar e colocar o formulário, mas quando volto a página não estou enviando formulário nenhum. Acontece que quando volto a página entrando na página de pesquisa de produtos que possui o formulário.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia evitar esse problema, utilizando Ajax, para o detalhar e colocar um botão voltar seu pra voltar pra listagem. 
Mas isso provavelmente mudaria demais a sua estrutura.
Mas teria um jeito mais eficiente, que é mudar a "ultima página acessada" por javascript, pra página detalhar sem os dados de formulário, não gerando a mensagem.
Você faria isso ao entrar na página do detalhar:

```
//Pra desativar o evento de voltar
window.onpopstate = function() {return false}; history.pushState({}, '');

//pra redirecionar pra tela de pesquisa sem os dados, não exibindo a mensagem
location = 'http://teladepesquisa.com/'
```

Comment: Na tela tenho um botão voltar, mas os usuários estão acostumados a usar o botão do celular.